# What does $classOverhead mean in hprof viewer?

Tags: android, hprof

When I open `hprof` files, I can see the following:

[image: Screenshot: $classOverhead in com.aliwork.baseutil.utils.SchedulerUtils$2]

However, I don't know what this means.